# Run hour calculation of 3 machines (eliminate overlapping time)

Tags: time, excel-formula

I have a list of 3 machine's run hour details, in that i have to eliminate overlapping time between each machine's run hour. As shown in the img. Please help on this & thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to calculate the overlap between each combination of two machines.

- Overlap between machine A and B in column I: `= IF( OR( B2 = 0; D2 = 0 ); 0; MAX( 0; MIN( C2; E2 ) - MAX( B2; D2 ) ) )`
- Overlap between machine B and C in column J: `= IF( OR( B2 = 0; F2 = 0 ); 0; MAX( 0; MIN( C2; G2 ) - MAX( B2; F2 ) ) )`
- Overlap between machine A and C in column K: `= IF( OR( D2 = 0; F2 = 0 ); 0; MAX( 0; MIN( E2; G2 ) - MAX( D2; F2 ) ) )`

The `IF( OR() )` statements are to controll for empty cells.

Now for the result, calculate the difference between the last end date and the earliest start date and substract the overlap: `= MAX( C2; E2; G2 ) - MIN( B2; D2; F2 ) - SUM( I2:K2 )`.

Copy down and that's it. Obviously you colud combine everything in one formula if you really want to, but that would be a very long formula and a bit of a mess.

PS: note that my machine uses semicolons instead of commas. Depending on your regional settings, you might have to replace the semicolons by commas.